# Component re-render on hovering drop container react-dnd

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I am using React-dnd for my drag and drop application. Whenever I hover the dragable  item on the drop container, the component re-renders itself. When re-rendering, the input property gets undefined because of what I am not able to refer to the input list to update the drop container list.

Comment: Any minimal reproducible code?